# AWStats combine page URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, awstats

I'm running AWStats on a Rails site with nginx and I have pages that are accessed like this

```
http://mysite.com/order/receipt/[receipt_tag]
```

I'd like for AWStats to show those as x hits for page `/order/receipt/*` instead of 1 hit for [tag x], and 1 for [tag y] and so on.  The closest directive I've found is `URLWithQueryWithoutFollowingParameters`, but since I'm using params as path components, I don't think that applies.

Same issue but with a (probably) more common scenario is combining ID's into one page.  So `/admin/orders/[order_id]` should be reported as x hits for `/admin/orders/*` instead of `/admin/orders/1` and `/admin/orders/2`, etc.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

A terrible solution that I'm using is to add all digits to awstat's URLQuerySeparators conf value, like

```
URLQuerySeparators="?;0123456789"
```

If you have numbers in the first part of your URL (like `/admin2/orders/1`) it won't work very well. Also, if you want to then have it look at query string values, I'm not sure how it'll behave.